# How to make WASM RazorComponents in MVC work when parameter types are in a different library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Following steps from guides like [this one](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/integrate-blazor-webassembly-existing-aspnet-core-web-application), and the [microsoft learn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) I have been trying to add blazor wasm to an existing MVC solution (dotnet 6). After getting the basics working I tried to create a component that takes an object as a parameter. That object's type is defined in a separate class library.

CounterWithMessageFromSharedAssembly.razor:

```cs
<p>Counter</p>

<p role="status">Message: @TestModel.Message</p>

<p role="status">Current count: @CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public TestModel2 TestModel { get; set; } = new TestModel2 { Message = "MESSAGE NOT SET"};

    [Parameter]
    public int CurrentCount { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        CurrentCount++;
    }
}
```

TestModel2.cs in class library:

```cs
namespace MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared;

public class TestModel2
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Component in mvc view:

```cs
    @{
        var testModel = new TestModel2
        {
            Message = "Successful test message"
        };
    }

    <component type="typeof(CounterWithMessageFromSharedAssembly)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" 
               param-CurrentCount="10"
               param-TestModel="@testModel" />
```

When running the application, prerendering works as expected but in the browser the component fails to start with the following error in the browser console:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The parameter 'TestModel' with type 'MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared.TestModel2' in assembly 'MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared' could not be found.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter 'TestModel' with type 'MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared.TestModel2' in assembly 'MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared' could not be found.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssemblyComponentParameterDeserializer.DeserializeParameters(IList`1 parametersDefinitions, IList`1 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder.InitializeRegisteredRootComponents(IJSUnmarshalledRuntime jsRuntime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder..ctor(IJSUnmarshalledRuntime jsRuntime, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(String[] args)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\workspace\MvcWithBlazorTest\mvc-with-blazor-test\MvcWithBlazorTest.Blazor\Program.cs:line 3
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples on how to reference types from other libraries in blazor webassembly. Here is a minimal code repo that reproduces the issue.  Is anyone able to help?

https://github.com/elexisvenator/mvc-with-blazor-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in the Program.cs of your webassembly project

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MvcWithBlazorTest.Shared.TestModel2>();
```

It's ok now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  Also, after some further testing, it appears that the specific thing missing is that at least 1 type from that assembly must be added to the webassembly program.cs, after that all types in that assembly will work.